# How to select referenced children entity referenced by a parent with criteria query using metamodel

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

i'm searching a way to select all children of a parent entity using the jpa criteria query API with metamodel.

**Table families**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FAMILIES")
public class Family {

 private Long familyId;
 private String familyName;
 private List<FamilyMember> familyMembers;

 @Id
 @Column(name="ID_FAMILY")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = Generator.AUTO)
 public Long getFamilyId() { return familyId;}
 public void setFamilyId(Long fId) { familyId = fId;}

 @Column(name = "family_name")
 public String getFamilyName() { return familyName;}
 public void setFamilyName(String fN) { familyName = fN;}

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "family")
 @JoinColumn(name = "id_family")
 public List<FamilyMember> getFamilyMembers() { return familyMembers;}
 public void setFamilyMembers(List<FamilyMember> fM) { familyMembers = fM}
```

}

**Table family_members**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "family_members")
public class FamilyMember {
 private Long familyMemberId;
 private Family family;
 private String name;
 private String role;

 @Id
 @Column(name="ID_FAMILY_MEMBER")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = Generator.AUTO)
 public Long getFamilyMemberId() { return familyMemberId;}
 public void setFamilyMemberId(Long fMId) { familyMemberId = fMId;}

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id_family")
 public String getFamily() { return family;}
 public void setFamily(Family f) { family = f;}

 @Column(name = "name")
 public String getFamilyMemberName() { return name;}
 public void setFamilyMemberName(String fMN) { name = fMN;}

 @Column(name = "role")
 public String getFamilyMemberRole() { return role;}
 public void setFamilyMemberRole(String fMR) { role = fMR;}
}
```

Now i would like to select all children entity of family, just when selecting family, instead of use a more slow approach to get a list of all family, loop through the list and populate the family member list.

To achieve this result qith plain SQL, i write a query like this:

```
SELECT f.family_name, fM.name, fM.role FROM families AS f LEFT JOIN family_members AS fM ON fM.id_family = f.id_family;
```

Now my question is, how can i translate this native query into a criteria API query.

Actually with criteria API i've tried this:

```
// Init of EntityManager (eM)
CriteriaBuilder cB = eM.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Family> fCQ = cB.createQuery(Family.class);
Root<Family> fromFamily = fCQ.from(Family.class);
// My actual implementation
ListJoin<Family, FamilyMember> members = fromFamily.join(Family_.familyMembers);
TypedQuery<Family> fTQ = eM.createQuery(fCQ);
```

But when i call the getResultList() i get a list containing only family entities, with a length of rows of families table multiplied by the rows of family_memebers.

Comment: To rephrase your question: what you want is a list of `Family` entities, along with the `Family.familyMembers` eagerly fetched, right? In such case, you want `fromFamily.fetch(...)` instead of `fromFamily.join(...)`.

Comment: Thank you crizzis, but `fetch` method accept metamodel attribute or only string?

Comment: Both versions exist (see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html)

Comment: Thank you crizzis, your suggestion worked perfectly. If you can post your first comment as an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rephrase your question: what you want is a list of Family entities, along with the `Family.familyMembers` eagerly fetched, right? In such case, you want `fromFamily.fetch(...)` instead of `fromFamily.join(...)`.